# Is this standard behavior for mapping plugin when used with requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, knockout-mapping-plugin

When using the mapping plugin without require js, you can simply bind to the variables by name only in the template. But when using require js I'm having to call them as a function. Is this normal?

For example: 
here a simple data-bind="text:boo" would work.

```
function loadPage() {
  require(['jquery', 'knockout', 'mapping'],function($,ko,mapping){
    ko.mapping = mapping;

    function viewModel() {
      this.moo = ko.observable('Hello');
      this.boo = ko.observable('World');
    }
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
  }
}
```

But for this, you need data-bind="text:boo()". The behavior without requirejs is the same as above. Am I mising something?

```
function loadPage() {
  require(['jquery', 'knockout', 'mapping'],function($,ko,mapping){
    ko.mapping = mapping;

    var data = {moo:'Hello', boo:'World'};
    var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the first example you didnt use the mapping plugin

Comment: I was just showing the difference. In the first example you can simply bind the variable, it works the same when you're using the mapping plugin without requirejs.

Comment: You can use ko.mapping.fromJS and mapping.fromJS indistinctly because the mapping plugin is AMD compliant

Comment: That was just to match my old code. Whatever you use, you end up having to do the text bind by calling the variable like a function. I was wondering why it was like that.

Comment: Have you tried var vm = {}; ko.mapping.fromJS(data, vm); Not sure this makes a difference.